# How to handle exception Unsupported image format from tess4j?

Tags: slf4j, tess4j

I'm trying to use tess4j to get a text from image, it's error:

"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported image format. May need to install JAI Image I/O package."

Although, I added JAI-imageio-core to dependencies.

```
File imageFile = new File("myFilePath");
    ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
    try {
        String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
        return result;
    } catch (TesseractException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        return "Error while reading image";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue with payara, copy the jai image io lib to your java dir 
C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk {version}\jre\lib\ext

This worked for me.

Tested with Payara / Wildfly 11

Comment: No problem, did my fix help or did it previously work?